# Can I use Apple's TestFlight with Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

Is there some way that I can use Apple's TestFlight (as opposed to the original TestFlight, which does still accept sign ups and can currently be used) with Xcode 5?

I want to be able to use Xcode 5 because Xcode 6 only works with the iOS 8 SDK. While there are hacks to make the iOS 7 SDK work with Xcode 6, they don't seem to successfully build an archive (I get link errors about the Metal framework for some architectures).

I wanted to use the iOS 7 SDK because our App needs some modifications to work with the iOS 8 SDK. This modifications are largely due to changes in the implementation details of autorotation, which is carried out at the window level under iOS 8. Some libraries we use rely on the iOS 7 approach and are broken under iOS 8. While we're happy to update all of this, we'd prefer to resolve it at a future time.

Comment: why do you say it's not longer accepting sign ups ? I just checked 15 seconds ago and it does

Comment: Interesting – me too. I was sure I'd read that they'd discontinued new sign ups. I'm wrong about that, I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer – **No**.

Longer answer…

I noticed that Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 share the same "Archives".

It is possible to create an archive build with Xcode 5 and then see this archive build in Xcode 6. You can use Xcode 6 to upload the build to iTunes Connect. This all works, and iTunes connect will let you distribute the build created in Xcode 5 to test devices. Using the TestFlight App on devices, they'll download and attempt to instal the build.

**However, the final step of installation fails**, and the TestFlight App asks you to come and try later on. Trying later never got me any further, so my conclusion is that the final installation step requires the build to have been created with the iOS 8 SDK (or later).